# Can you only have one hibernate session per thread in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

So I'm working on an application without multi threading. We have a main business logic method that opens a Hibernate session like this:

```
session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
```

and then performs some light DB operations (a few selects). A method that I've overridden in a subclass is then called that needs to perform another select. I can't pass the session as a parameter without having to update 20ish subclasses.

I tried opening a new session and transaction and closing them when I was done, but when my method kicked back to the business method, I got an error that the session was closed. I tried not closing the session and committing the transaction, but that wasn't working either.

Right now I'm just using this and everything seems to be working properly locally:

```
session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
tx = session.getTransaction();
```

and I'm only closing the session and rolling back incase of errors. I'm just uncertain if getSession will always return the session thats already open. Am I right to assume that only one session can be open at a time per thread?

Here's the implementation of getSession:

```
Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen())
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            rebuildSessionFactory();
        }
        session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession() : null;
        threadLocal.set(session);
    }

    return session;
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession() will achieve, and you also need to config https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html, because `SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession()` actually call `CurrentSessionContext.currentSession()` method to return Session. Usually `CurrentSessionContext.currentSession()` implementation is one Session per thread.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, getSession will return a new hibernate session.   There are two methods of using sessions in Hibernate that is described transactional patterns in the document: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html

The actual "session" to the database depends on your connection to the database.   Most people utilize a connection pool, like C3P0 that can be used to ensure session reuse and speed up your code.

The  best structure I use is to create a SessionFactory once in application launch, as this sets up the connection pool to the database.   Then, utilizing maybe a singleton pattern to keep a single SessionFactory, request new sessions for each transaction you perform from the single SessionFactory.   Hibernate will utilize the underlying connection pool to handle session reuse for speed and optimization.