# Concurrent @Transactional method calls do not really happen concurrently

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, concurrency, transactions

I have a test that starts 40 threads concurrently which each of them run the same method.

Without @Transactional annotation on that method, the method calling time is more or less the same in all threads. (even down to milliseconds level)

With @Transactional, the method calls are kind of in sequence! (Each method call has about 0.1 sec delay).

So why is it so?

Actually I am testing the isolation level, with such test to see if dirty read can occur with level READ_UNCOMMITTED.

But such delay simply make the queries/transactions not concurrent!

```
public void saveOrUpdateRecord(Record record) throws NoAvailableRecordException {
LOGGER.debug("saveOrUpdateRecord called");
int currentPoolSize = recordDao.getActiveRecordSize(record
    .getCreatedTime());
LOGGER.debug("saveOrUpdateRecord:: currentPoolSize: " + currentPoolSize);
if (currentPoolSize >= 30) {
  throw new NoAvailableRecordException();
}

recordDao.save(record);}
```

This is the function called.

Below are the DAO function,

```
public int getActiveRecordSize(Date asOfTime) throws DataAccessException {
String hql = "from Record record where record.expiryTime > :asOfTime";
return this.getHibernateTemplate()
    .findByNamedParam(hql, "asOfTime", asOfTime).size();}




public void save(Record record) throws DataAccessException {
try {
  this.getHibernateTemplate().save(record);
  this.getHibernateTemplate().flush();
} catch (HibernateException hex) {
  throw this.convertHibernateAccessException(hex);
}}
```

Answers and suggestions are very welcomed. :)

Comment: Please specify what kind of queries are executing in method and how you measure time (is 0.1 sec from outer call to reach start of the internal call all it's the whole method execution time)

Comment: @qwwdfsad

public void saveOrUpdateRecord(Record record) throws NoAvailableRecordException {
    LOGGER.debug("saveOrUpdateRecord called");
    int currentPoolSize = recordDao.getActiveRecordSize(newlyConstructedToken
        .getCreatedTime());
    LOGGER.debug("saveOrUpdateRecord:: currentPoolSize: " + currentPoolSize);
    if (currentTokenPoolSize >= tokenPoolSize) {
      throw new NoAvailableRecordException();
    }

    recordDao.save(record);
  }

Comment: better to do it in question :)

Comment: @qwwdfsad i have put the codes in question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, with the `@Transactional` annotation each thread tries to get its own transaction, and as the number of concurrent transactions is restricted, threads eventually get blocked.

You might have a look to your actual

```
hibernate.connection.pool_size
```

As suggested in [Hibernate usage with a lot of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927543/hibernate-usage-with-a-lot-of-threads) , the use of a connection pool may help you to deal with concurrent transactions (as your database also have a limit on the number of parallel transactions you don't want to exceed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really gave a new direction to me for the problem solving. In my case, the root cause is the maxActive is set to 1 in tomcat JDBC setting.